# combine two column for dev express checkedcomboboxedit value member property

Tags: c#, devexpress, checkbox

I use a datatable to fill checkedCombobocEdit control. My datatable has three column( suppose that ). I use the "name" column for display member and also I need to use the "id" and the "version" column for value member(combining both of two). It is possible?

```
myDatabaseProcessClass getTable = new myDatabaseProcessClass();
DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit properties = myCheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties;

properties.DataSource = getTable.GetProductInformation(0, 0);

properties.ValueMember = ;// Combine "Id" column and "Version" column
properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: How do you get your items from the database ?

Comment: The ORM (Object-relational mapping) of DevExpress, can you post how do you get "myDataTable", it could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 you can use Expression on new column, this column is created with combination of two columns.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

And bind with the new column

2 You can also use this syntax in order to combine two columns : "Column1" + "Column2"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add class with the members you want for your data, and add the FullId property (Id + Version)

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Version { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}

    public string FullId { get {return String.Format("{0}{1}", Id, Version)}}
}
```

And write a class that get the list of items for you

```
public class MyController
{
    public List<MyModel> GetItems()
    {
         var list = new List<MyModel>();
         //fill the list from your database

         return list;
    }
}
```

And then, use the property FullId as ValueMember, in your load for example :

```
private Load()
{
    var controller = new MyController();
    richeckedCom.Properties.DataSource = controller.GetItems();

    properties.ValueMember = "FullId";
    properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Comment: Better use a separator between the Id's. What if you have one object with `{Id="1",Version="23"}` and other with `{Id="12",Version="3"}`, because both will have `FullId="123"`.

Comment: I missed that one, Thanks :-)